# Vue CORS in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors

I'm a beginner in Vue and now I'm fighting with CORS problem.
While **developing** my app (http://localhost:8080/) sends a request to http://zz.zz.zz.zz:3000/ and these code helped me to fix CORS:

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://zz.zz.zz.zz:3000/"
  }
};
```

But when my app is in **production** (http://zz.zz.zz.zz:3001/) sends a request to http://zz.zz.zz.zz:3000/ it gets CORS error. I tried the code below but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

**.env.production & .env.development**

```js
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://zz.zz.zz.zz:3000/
```

example of a request in component:

```js
let url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "?name=anna";
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.file);
const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
};
axios
  .post(url, formData, config)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
```

**(CORS are allowed on the server)**

Here's **package.json**:

```js
{
  "name": "PROJECT_1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
    "vue-plugin-load-script": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @kazibek, did you ever find an answer to this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you get CORS error, this means that either the CORS are not enabled on your backend or misconfigured.
=> You need to enable CORS on your backend so that it return CORS headers in backend response.

Check the header of your backend responses to ensure that CORS are properly configured ie:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I only have allow credentials true. But is it normal when CORS appears when the app sends a request to the same network, but another port?

Comment: If your front and backend are not on the same `domain` or on the same `port`, your backend needs to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Otherwise the browser will block comunications between front and back. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Use [vue-axios-cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios-cors)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import AxiosPlugin from 'vue-axios-cors';
 
Vue.use(AxiosPlugin)
```

then you can use axios in your project like you generally do.